# How get and store each property of geojson

Tags: java

First of all, apologize for the grammatical errors that you can make. My English is not very good.

I'm trying to store properties of each item from geojson.

I would like store them into an array like this:

Array: [ [prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4], ... ]

My problem is that property "item" is an object that contains each proeprty.

Can you help me?

Here is [geojson file](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/earthquakes.geojson).

Here is my code:

```
public void loadProperties() {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray(ApiJSON.FEATURES);
    Iterator<Object> iterator = array.iterator();

    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) iterator.next();
        for (String key : jsonObject.keySet()) {
            if (key.equalsIgnoreCase(ApiJSON.PROPERTIES)) {

                JSONObject item = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get(key);
                for (int i=0; i<keyNames.size(); i++) {
                    String keyName = keyNames.get(i).toString();
                    Object value = item.get(keyName);
                    properties.put(keyName, value);
                }

            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(properties.toString());
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what an element in an array should look like?

Comment: You might want to look into www.geotools.org

Answer (score 0):

I solved, thanks a lot for your help :D

```
public void loadProperties() {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray(ApiJSON.FEATURES);
    Iterator<Object> iterator = array.iterator();

    list = new ArrayList<>();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) iterator.next();
        for (String key : jsonObject.keySet()) {
            if (key.equalsIgnoreCase(ApiJSON.PROPERTIES)) {

                JSONObject item = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get(key);
                Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                for (int i=0; i<keyNames.size(); i++) {
                    String keyName = keyNames.get(i).toString();
                    Object value = item.get(keyName);
                    props.put(keyName, value);
                }
                list.add(props);
            }
        }
    }
}
```